# Fetch data from text file to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have here an HTML page which is supposed to be fetching a list of data, but apparently due to server migration ASP is not working. So I want to fetch data without using any language but just pure JavaScript and an HTML page. I think that storing my data in a text file (`.txt`) and fetching it via JavaScript will do. And the condition will be every month there is different text file to be fetched. Is this possible?

Comment: I would look on how to complete the migration... What you ask is how to make a bandaid stick on an untreated wound... That will soon get infected. ;)

Comment: Where is this text file located? If it's on the same server, you might consider server side includes. If it's somewhere else, you can fetch it with ajax. jQuery is good for this: `$.get('http://path/to/file.txt', function(data) { $("#target").html(data); });`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you for your suggestion. But due to server migration asp is not supported anymore and we are not allowed to use other language. So come up with the idea I posted.

Comment: @mankowitz Hello. Yup, the text file would be on the same server. Would you mind helping me to do that? I don't have any codes to startup so far. Sorry =/

Comment: It depends on which server you are using. If Apache, you'd do something like this `<!--#include file="filename.html"-->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"
  }).done(function(response) {
    $('#data').html(response);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></p>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"
  }).done(function(response) {
    $('#data').html(response);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="data"></p>
</body>
</html>
```